# macro para copiar e colar

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Tenho dados na coluna "M", que são introduzidos automaticamente, numa média de 70 linhas por mês, só que tem intervalos de células vazias (os 12 meses do ano estão na coluna "M").

Então queria copiar esses dados por mês, para a coluna "N", automaticamente sem esses intervalos.

Vou tentar explicar de outra maneira:

```
coluna M          coluna N
M1=4                   N1=4
M2=                    N2=20
M3=20                  N3=2
M4=2                   N4=10
M5=                     
M6=
M7=
M8=10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bom dia @Mario Felicio

Segue o código da Macro:

```
Sub CopyPaste()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim qtde As Integer
    Dim linFrom As Integer
    Dim linTo As Integer
    Dim colFrom As String
    Dim colTo As String

    'inicializando minhas variáveis
    colFrom = "M"
    colTo = "N"
    linFrom = 1
    linTo = 1

    'Definindo qual a planilha
    Set ws = Worksheets("Plan1")
    'Identificando qual a última linha
    qtde = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, colFrom).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    'fazendo um loop até o meu último registro da coluna de Origem
    While linFrom <= qtde
        'verificando se a minha célula de origem possui valor
        If ws.Cells(linFrom, colFrom) <> "" Then
            'se houver valor, copio para a minha célula de destino
            ws.Cells(linTo, colTo) = ws.Cells(linFrom, colFrom)
            'passando para minha próxima linnha de destino
            linTo = linTo + 1
        End If
        'passando para minha próxima linha de origem
        linFrom = linFrom + 1

    Wend

End Sub
```

Note que coloquei as colunas M e N em variáveis para facilitar caso você precise alterar as colunas de origem e destino.

Basta copiar o código acima, entrar no menu desenvolvedor / Visual Basic, colar esse código e salvar. Depois basta clicar em Macros e selecioná-la.

Lembrando que sua planilha terá que ser salva com suporte a Macros.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: amigo Thomas. é isto mesmo que queria, alterei "linfrom=1";"linto=1", para separar os meses, também alterei "while linfrom<=qtde", para a última linha de cada mês. ou seja fiz 12 modulos, cada um com estas linhas alteradas. está a funcionar.

Comment: Maravilha...!!!